# React Native: Convert State/Context code from Functional Component to Class Component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a simple React-Native app setup in which I use Context to share some data throughout components. I have some code setup for functional components but I would like to convert it to Class component code. Anyone who could help me further?

All that needs to be changed is the way context in de screens and state is handled.

UserContext.js (this one doesn't need changing just putting it here for context.)

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

AccountScreen.js

```
export default function AccountScreen() {
    const { User, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>ID: {User}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const [User, setUser] = useState("yessir");

    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{User, setUser}}>
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}}/>
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}}/>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </PaperProvider>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Home function for nav:

```
function Home(){
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator 
    barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#191919'}}
    shifting={true}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={HomeScreen} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Feed',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          )
        }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="magnify" color={color} size={26} />
          )
        }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Account',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
          )
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A  simple way is to write a higher-order component (HOC) with can provide user context props to any component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);

const withUserContext = (Component) => (props)=> {
  return (
    <UserContext.Consumer>
      {(userContext) => <Component {...props} userContext={userContext}/>
      }
    </UserContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default withUserContext;
```

AccountScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import withUserContext from "./withUserContext";

class AccountScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { User, setUser } = this.props.userContext;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>ID: {User}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withUserContext(AccountScreen);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but a couple of things:

- With the `export default withUserContext(Account);`, what does the `(Account)` refer to? Is that supposed to be `AccountScreen`? Also because you're not exporting the `AccountScreen` the navigation doesn't work because the Screen is being passed into it as a Component.

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo mistake.  I update the answer

Comment: If you can take a look at the edit, you can see the function being passed as a component which contains the accountscreen which it doesn't see as a valid component anymore.

Comment: I have updated the answer with test example:

https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: This idea will lead to props drilling.... to a very deep nasted components which leads to hard to maintain states and application...

Comment: Technically this is what all your favorite packages do, React Navigation, React-redux, and more.  Developer will not need to pass props manually, just export components that need global state with HOC and use state in that component.

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel Does the app go to the AccScreen in your snack.expo for you?

Comment: Yes. I added it as the third screen on the tab, just for experimentation.

https://imgur.com/a/2vECyCA